# Pushing results to array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, push

```
<tr>
    <td>1st</td>
    <td class="result horse1"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2nd</td>
    <td class="result horse2"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>3rd</td>
    <td class="result horse3"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>4th</td>
    <td class="result horse4"></td>
</tr>
```

This is a game in javascript and when the horse crosses the line it will execute the `this.finish` function.

It will get the results and display them in a table by changing classes to include the `ID`. This works fine but when I then push the `ID` into the array it will only store two of the id's before throwing an error.

```
if (horse.lap == laps && horse.x == horse.startX + 5) {
    horse.finish();
}   

this.finish = function() {
    this.element.className = 'horse standRight';
    var table = document.getElementsByClassName('result');
    table[results.length].className = id;
    results.push(id);
    console.log(results);
  }

var results = [];
```

When displaying the results in the table, it also skip the 2nd row and place an id in the third row?

This is the error[image: hors3, crossed first, horse1 second then break.]

Comment: Since you replace the classname with just ID, `document.getElementsByClassName('result')` returns a smaller number of items each time while your `results` array is growing each time. Eventually the array becomes longer than `document.getElementsByClassName('result')` and then `table[results.length]` returns undefined.

Comment: "by changing classes to include the ID"...but your code doesn't _include_ the ID into the classes, it _replaces_ all the other classes with just the ID

Comment: I see, cheers guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned the comments, you're replacing the entire classname with id, so the "result" in the className is gone too.

You can instead replace the horse ID part alone with the new one i.e.

`table[results.length].className = "result " + id;`

OR

```
var currentClass = table[results.length].className;
table[results.length].className = currentClass.replace(/horse[0-9]/,id);
```

There are more ways to do this too, including splitting the classname by space  etc.